# sql mapping to json object

Tags: java, sql, json

I am looking for a better approach of mapping my query to json object.

Structure of json object is -

```
{
   "year":"2020",
   "month":[
      {
         "name":"January",
         "month":"1",
         "payroll_dates":[
            "1",
            "2"
         ],
         "holiday_dates":[
            "3",
            "4"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Feburary",
         "month":"2",
         "payroll_dates":[
            "1",
            "2"
         ],
         "holiday_dates":[
            "3",
            "4"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"March",
         "month":"3",
         "payroll_dates":[
            "1",
            "2"
         ],
         "holiday_dates":[
            "3",
            "4"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"April",
         "month":"4",
         "payroll_dates":[
            "1",
            "2"
         ],
         "holiday_dates":[
            "3",
            "4"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"May",
         "month":"5",
         "payroll_dates":[
            "1",
            "2"
         ],
         "holiday_dates":[
            "3",
            "4"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and database design is :

```
   id | calendarDt | year | month | day | calendarType
   1. | 2020-1-25  | 2020 | 1     | 25  | Holiday
    2 | 2020-1-22  | 2020 | 1     | 22  | Holiday
    3 | 2020-1-13  | 2020 | 1     | 13  | Payday
```

These are the details of january month for holiday and payday.

The java code i have used is :

created a list for each month for holiday.
Created a list for each month for payroll.
Created an object for each month.
And then set the list in the month object.

Is there a better approach for doing it in java?

```
    List<String> payrollStringJan= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> holidayStringJan = new ArrayList<String>();
    Month janMonth = new Month();

    for (Calendar item: payrollCalendarList) {

        switch(item.getMonth()) {

        case 1:
            populateMonthObject(item, payrollStringJan, 
            holidayStringJan);
            break;

          }

            private void populateMonthObject(UhgCalendar item, 
         List<String> payrollString, List<String> holidayString) {
    if("Payday".equals(item.getCalendarType())) {
        payrollString.add(Integer.toString(item.getDay()));
    }
    if("Holiday".equals(item.getCalendarType())) {
        holidayString.add(Integer.toString(item.getDay()));
    }
}
```

Json pojo -

```
       public class PayrollCalendar {

    @JsonProperty("year")
    private String year;
    @JsonProperty("month")
    private List<Month> month = null;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 //getter setter follow
} 

    public class Month {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("month")
    private String month;
    @JsonProperty("payroll_dates")
    private List<String> payrollDates = null;
    @JsonProperty("holiday_dates")
    private List<String> holidayDates = null;
    //getter setter follow
}
}
```

Comment: Why dont you create a Java object which accept the Json structure  and manipulate ?

Comment: I have a json object..  but i want better manipulation technique .. so my query is select * from calendar where year = '2020' /.. i am creating a list for each month for payroll and holiday .. and i am creating 12 month objects

Comment: I Understood What I am trying to tell you is  Instead  of you manipulating by json key . why dont you deserialize the string So that you dont need to write this many lines  .

Comment: how can that be done? any example?

Comment: You have to create a pojo class which should accept Above JSON format .

Comment: I do have apojo class. .. my problem is a better approach in java while setting values in the pojo..

Comment: Why you need to set Do Json deserialize ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to understand why the database is designed so. The database can just have calendar date and calendar type. If you want the holiday/Payday in a given month or few months or in a year, you can write the query easily.

In terms of Json object, it can simply have a payday array and a holiday array if the client wants all the dates and I don't think response will be too big for this use-case.